Not being able to get URL parameter from URL in WP Engine hosted WooCommerce site
I have this WordPress site where I use WooCommerce for payments. Once a payment is done and the order is complete, a presigned url is generated from R2 bucket in cloudflare and it is appended to the URL of the page that streams the video:
<?php
/*
Template Name: Movie Player
*/

get_header();

$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? esc_url($_GET['url']) : '';

if ($url):

    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($url); // Print the final URL for debugging
    echo '</pre>'; 
?>  
    <video controls controlsList="nodownload">
        <source src="<?php echo $url; ?>" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Disable right-click context menu
            });
             // Log the video URL to the console
             console.log("Video URL:", "<?php echo $url; ?>");
        });
    </script>
<?php
else:
    echo 'No video URL provided.';
endif;

get_footer();

This is the function that generates the presigned url in functions.php.
function handle_order_complete($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if ($order->has_status('completed')) {
        // Retrieve the bucket name and object key from environment variables
        $bucketName = 'ngop-movie';
        $objectKey = 'kot-2-movie.mp4';

        // Generate the pre-signed URL
        $presignedUrl = generate_presigned_url($bucketName, $objectKey);

        // Redirect the user to the movie player page with the pre-signed URL
        wp_redirect('https://kotthemovie.com/movie-stream?url=' . urlencode($presignedUrl));
        exit;
    }
}

In my video player page I retrieve the parameter from the url and use it as source to stream the video. It works fine locally with localhost but on my deployed wordpress site in WP Engine I am not able to retrieve the parameter and add it to the source of the video. The video player doesn't show at all. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?
I tried changing the network settings for my custom domain from GES to advanced network but apparently this didn't resolve the issue. Also I contacted support and they excluded the parameter from being stripped and this still didn't work.

I've occasionally needed to register my query string keys with the query_vars hook, I'd try that first
